# Can't open file error uploading file via FTPLIB and Python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to upload a file using ftplib and python. I continue getting this error and don't know why...help?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\212392169\Desktop\ftp_trial.py", line 15, in <module>
    ftp.storbinary("STOR samplee.bin", f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 471, in storbinary
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 376, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 339, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 249, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 224, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
    ftplib.error_perm: 550 Can't open file "samplee.bin"
```

Source Code:

```
from ftplib import FTP    
ftp = FTP(host)

ftp.login(host,pw)    
ftp.cwd("/dflts")

f = open('samplee.bin', 'rb')
ftp.storbinary("STOR samplee.bin", f)
f.close()
ftp.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you don't have permission to upload the file.

```
ftp.login(host, pw)
          ^^^^
```

Is the `host` really what you meant?